# How to integrate two python folders?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10

I have python located at two places in my OS(C:) drive.

One is at   [Folder1]    C:\Python38

Other is at [Folder2]    C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32

Most of Folder1 and Folder2 are same, but when I run, say,  `pip install matplotlib` , it shows some requirements satisfied in Folder1, while the others in Folder2.

```
pip install matplotlib
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (3.2.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.11 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.18.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.4.7)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (0.10.0)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (1.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\python38\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib) (2.8.1)
Requirement already satisfied: six in c:\users\user\appdata\roaming\python\python38\site-packages (from cycler>=0.10->matplotlib) (1.14.0)
```

However, I want all that in one place, so as to be able to delete either Folder1 or Folder2 to free up space. How do i do that?

Comment: Are you sure the first isn’t just a shortcut to the second? Did you install Python yourself? Also, can you share an example of the pip output which mentions both locations?

Comment: @AMC I have edited the question accordingly. Also, both take up large space; so definitely nothing is a shortcut.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the one in `C:\Users\User\AppData\Local...` is 32-bit, while the one in `C:\Python38` is the 64-bit version.

I would recommend uninstalling both, and doing a clean install.

If you don't want to remove both, I would recommend removing one of them from your PATH variables, and see if everything works fine.

Keep in mind there are 2 options in the installer, one is for all users(will put python in program files folder) and the other one is per user (will be in users local appdata)